# Java Distance between two Vector positions never 0

Tags: java, mathematics, vector

I have a Player moving, but when the player reaching the destination it should stop. But problem is that distance never return 0.

It starts printing this:
0.9672514210000003

End by this and then start to raise back again:
0.0015875672000023044

```
// My position is 5.0 and toPosition is either +1 or -1
if (getDistance(getPosition(), toPosition) <= 0) {
    allowMovement = false;
}

public double getDistance (PositionVector pos1, PositionVector pos2) {
    double dx = pos1.x - pos2.x;
    double dy = pos1.y - pos2.y;
    return Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
}
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mathematically speaking, a distance is a value which is never lower than 0. You can see this thing in your `getDistance()` function implementation: the argument passed to the square root function is a sum between powers of 2. A power of 2 is always positive, their sum is positive as well, and the `sqrt()` function will always give back a positive value. So, no real reason to have your condition checking for a value smaller than 0.

The reason your distance check isn't going to evaluate to 0 is your player object's origin isn't aligned with the final position along any axis, so there will be only a minimum distance between they two:

[image]

You can fix this in two different ways, depending on your game:

**Higher minimum distance**
This approach is very simple, as you have a special area defined by a volume or just a distance radius, and events are performed when the player lies inside the area. To implement this tecnique, you can simply change the distance value in your code with a value higher than 0:

```
// Check if player is at hot position
int safeDistance = 30;  // Choose your desired value
if (getDistance(getPosition(), toPosition) <= safeDistance) {
    allowMovement = false;
}
```

**Axis distance**
Easier approach, instead of checking a distance to a point, you focus on one coordinate only. Works best with side-scrolling platformers, where you can move over a given horizontal coordinate from one way only, for example. Such x-axis coordinate may be the very end of the current level, like in Super Mario Bros. or similar.

In my opinion, the first one is the best one. This way you can force the player to get to a particular position in your level to progress during the game.

Comment: If it helped you to solve your problem, you may want to mark it as right answer :)

Comment: Also, be very careful about comparing with zero with floating-point numbers. You should instead see if the distance is less than some small epsilon.